# Random selected strings

Tags: java, string, random

I have a text file and i am trying to convert every line into an ArrayList. Then i have to take a random line from this text.file and display it on new JOptionPane.

I am trying to implement it in the for-loop but it always appears only the first line from my text.file. Thank you very much and here is my code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    ArrayList<String> allQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> allRandomSelectedQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();
    File file = new File("C:/Users/User/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SummerExamProject/src/Questions2.txt");
    int numberOfRandomQuestions = 16;

    try {
        //Read line by line from the file  
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = scan.nextLine();

            //  System.out.println(line);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line.replace("/", "\n"));

            scan.close();

            allQuestions.add(line); 
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRandomQuestions; i++){
        Random randNum = new Random();

        int randQuestionIndex = randNum.nextInt(numberOfRandomQuestions);   
        String randomQuestion = allQuestions.get(randQuestionIndex); 
        allRandomSelectedQuestions.add(randomQuestion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StackTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        actionPerformed();
    }

    public static void actionPerformed() {

        ArrayList<String> allQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();
        File file = new File("D:/me/test.txt");
        int numberOfRandomQuestions = 10;
        try {
            // Read line by line from the file
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                allQuestions.add(line);
            }
            scan.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRandomQuestions; i++) {
            Random randNum = new Random();

            int randQuestionIndex = randNum.nextInt(numberOfRandomQuestions);
            System.out.println();
            String randomQuestion = allQuestions.get(randQuestionIndex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, randomQuestion.replace("/", "\n"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works and gives me random question. Thank you very much. But when I open a new JOptionPane and then try to close it it continuous to show me the all other  questions from the text.file  and they close when they reach the end of the text.file!

Comment: sorry but not getting your problem you facing, can you please elaborate it? Do you want to open only one dialog at a time?

Comment: Yes, I have 16 JButtons that do the same thing. When I press one of them  it opens a JOptionPane with randomQuestion from my text.file, but when i click OK or Close on this JOptionPane it seems that the scan hasn't stopped and it continuous showing every other single question from this file in new JOptionPane-s.

Comment: do you want only one question while ruining program once?

Comment: Yes I want when I click on my JButton to show a question and then answer it, after that i can choose another button from my 16-JButtons and load another question.

Comment: It's another question again. You need to write your logic on click event of question dialog ok button. This question was getting random question instead of only first. :) Ask another question for it.

Comment: Also, if any answer satisfy your question requirements, then you should accept it and upvote it so other readers can see it :)

Answer (score 1):

This line...

```
scan.close();
```

Is inside your `while` loop, so it closes the file after reading a line the first time it goes through the loop.

Moving it to after the loop (i.e. after the close culry-brace) ought to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this: `scan.close();`. You are closing your scanner in the same loop you are using for reading. Moving it outside the loop body should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Call close method after the while loop. What is happening that, you close after the first line. so the while loop stops after only one time.

```
 while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

          String line = scan.nextLine();
          //System.out.println(line);
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line.replace("/", "\n"));
          allQuestions.add(line); 
    }
    scan.close();
```